# clock_settime doesn't work with CLOCK_REALTIME

Tags: c, linux, time

I wrote a sample code to set the time using clock_settime.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    struct timespec walltime;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &walltime);
    perror("clock_gettime");
    printf("Current wall time:%s\n", ctime(&walltime.tv_sec));

    walltime.tv_sec += 10*60;
    printf("Setting wall time to :%s\n", ctime(&walltime.tv_sec));
    clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &walltime);
    perror("clock_settime");

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &walltime);
    perror("clock_gettime");
    printf("Current wall time:%s\n", ctime(&walltime.tv_sec));
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the program:

```
clock_gettime: Success
Current wall time:Mon Nov  4 03:24:43 2019

Setting wall time to :Mon Nov  4 03:34:43 2019

clock_settime: Success
clock_gettime: Success
Current wall time:Mon Nov  4 03:34:43 2019
```

Looks correct, but when i run it the second time, the new time is not updated.

```
clock_gettime: Success
Current wall time:Mon Nov  4 03:25:12 2019

Setting wall time to :Mon Nov  4 03:35:12 2019

clock_settime: Success
clock_gettime: Success
Current wall time:Mon Nov  4 03:35:12 2019
```

Date command also shows the old value.

```
$ date
Mon Nov  4 03:25:30 PST 2019
```

Is this behavior correct

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should generally never check the value of `errno` (which you do through `perror`) unless the function explicitly failed. Otherwise the value of `errno` is indeterminate.

Comment: Is the system connected to a network?  Most likely the time is "corrected" periodically by NTP.  Disable the  NTP service if you don't want that to happen.

Comment: How can i disable that?

Comment: That will depend on your Linux distribution.  Google it - that's what I did, I never use Linux if I don't have to!  It is also not an SO question is it comes down to that. You need https://serverfault.com/

Comment: If you set the system time with the `date` command on your system, does it stick or get reset a bit later?